# Show that $\equiv$ is a congruence on $M\times S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, localization, monoid, congruence-relations

I'm sorry if a similar question has been posted before, but I was unable to find one based on my searches. This is an extra practice problem for a number theory class. I've been trying to prove this out, and I'm getting stuck on the transitivity step. This is also a check on myself to make sure that I understand what I need to demonstrate in order to show a congruence.

Here is the full question. I include the last sentence for extra context:

> For a submonoid $S$ of a commutative monoid $(M,*)$, define a relation $\equiv$ on the monoid $M\times S$ by $(a,s)\equiv(b,t)$ if there is a $u\in S$ such that $a*t*u=b*s*u$. Show that $\equiv$ is a congruence on $M\times S$. $M$ is a commutative monoid $M$ and $S$ is an arbitrary submonoid of $M$.

Here's what I've written so far. Since I'm dealing with monoids, I don't think I need the part that starts "And finally" (that only applies to groups). Please let me know if I'm mistaken:

---

> We want to see that $\equiv$ is a congruence. That means we need to demonstrate that $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation. Then we want to see that for any $(a,s),(a',s'),(b,t),(b',t') \in M \times S$, if $(a,s) \sim (a',s')$ and $(b,t) \sim (b',t')$, then $(a,s)*(b,t) \sim (a',s')*(b',t')$. **And finally**, we want to see that for any $(a,s),(a',s') \in M \times S$, if $(a,s) \sim (a',s')$, then $(a,s)^{-1} \sim (a',s')^{-1}$. Note that $a*t*u=b*s*u$ implies that $u \in S$ is at least right cancellable. And since $S$ is a submonoid of a commutative monoid $M$, $u$ is left cancellable, thus cancellable in general.
>
> First, we'll demonstrate that $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation.
>
> *Reflexivity*
>
> Suppose that $a*s*u=a*s*u$. Then it follows immediately that $(a,s) \equiv (a,s)$.
>
> *Symmetry*
>
> Suppose that $a*t*u=b*s*u$. Then $(a,s),(b,t) \in M \times S$, and $(a,s) \equiv (b,t)$. Since $=$ is an equality, we have $(b,t) \equiv (a,s)$.
>
> *Transitivity*
>
> Suppose that $a*t*u_1=b*s*u_1$ and $b*v*u_2=c*t*u_2$ where $u_1,u_2 \in S$.

---

At this point, I'm stuck trying to show how $(a,s) \equiv (c,v)$. I've tried writing this out multiplicatively, and I thought I would have to use the fact that $u$ is cancellable, but I don't know how to proceed without violating rules.

For instance, I've written on scratch paper:
$\frac{a}{t}*\frac{1}{u_1}=\frac{b}{s}*\frac{1}{u_1}$ and $\frac{b}{v}*\frac{1}{u_2}=\frac{c}{t}*\frac{1}{u_2}$. I know that I want to be able to say $\frac{a}{v}*\frac{1}{u_3}=\frac{c}{s}*\frac{1}{u_3}$, but I'm not sure how to get there. I've also written this additively but that led to a dead end as well.

Thanks ahead of time for any help / hints / clues.

Comment: You have a typo for the transitivity relation for $(b,t)\equiv (c,v)$. Should be $bvu_2=ctu_2$. And you're right, you skip the and finally part as you're dealing with monoids where there are no guarantee of inverses to exist.

Comment: You're right. I had written it correctly on my scratch paper but typed it up wrong. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $atu_1=bsu_1$ and $bvu_2=ctu_2$ for some $a,b\in M$, $s,t,u_1,u_2\in S$.

Multiplying the first equation by $u_2v$, and noting that multiplication is associative and commutative in this setting, we get
$$(av)(u_1u_2t)=atu_1u_2v=bsu_1u_2v=(bvu_2)u_1s=(ctu_2)u_1s=(cs)(u_1u_2t).$$
Observe that $u_1u_2t\in S$ since $S$ is a submonoid.

Comment: Thanks. I think that makes sense. But why is s,t in S? I would have thought it would be in M, if it matters.

Comment: That's part of the assumption since $(a,s),(b,t),(c,v)\in M\times S$.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help. Hope it made sense as I omitted the asterisks for easy typesetting.

Comment: If anything it makes more sense. I think the asterisks were throwing me off (long day).

Comment: Hey just trying to finish up this problem, and seeing if you're around to critique my work. I want to show that $\equiv$ is compatible with the binary operation. So I wrote:

Let $a * s' * u_1 = a' * s * u_1$ and $b * t' * u_2 = b' * t * u_2$. Then $(a,s) \sim (a',s')$ and $(b,t) \sim (b',t')$, and we have:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(a,s)*(b,t) &= (a,s)*(b',t')\\
&= (a',s')*(b',t') \\
(ab,st) &= (a'b',s't')  
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Since $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation and compatible with $*$, we can conclude that $\equiv$ is a congruence relation.

Comment: Sorry, what's the definition of compatible with the binary operation?

Comment: I don't think the binary operation in $M \times S$ is defined. I just defined it myself the traditional way: for $(a,b),(c,d) \in M \times S$, then $(a,b)*(c,d)=(ac,bd)$. Not sure if I'm allowed to do that, but figured I'd try.